# Units of of results from 2 dimensional FFT in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have a two dimensional numpy array (say `arr`) which contain values in a two dimensional coordinate map. This array has one value for every (10 meters , 10 meters) in (x,y) coordinate system. The array `arr` is of shape `(4,4)`. The positions of centers of bins of `arr` are 10 meters apart.

The figure given below shows a picture of `arr`:[image]

I am doing a 2 dimensional discrete Fourier Transformiation of `arr` to obtain `arr_fft` in the following manner:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fftn as np_fftn

arr = np.array( [ [125, 592, 29, 6512] , [529, 612, 295, 55] , [1212, 125, 2912, 612], [512, 9205, 925, 555] ] )
arr_fft = np_fftn( arr )
```

A picture of `arr_fft` can be found below (the labels of axes may be wrong, since I am unsure about what the values and units of the midpoints of bins of `arr_fft` should be):

[image]

In the above picture (`arr_fft`), what should be the correct units and values of the x and y axes? Thanks in advance.

The full code that I have used for plotting can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gR8OWZuaDLE3HD_-nxhJqpPOUoKhCfYU/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The unit should be 1 / meters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients you get from an FFT on a spatial dimension represent [**wavenumber**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber), which is broadly analogous to frequency when dealing with time series.

The units of wavenumber are **m<sup>−1</sup>**, and are unnamed in the SI system.